# Disable "Loading..." mode while preoading images in Opera

Tags: image, opera, preloading, image-preloader

There is **crossdomain** image, which is loaded for **30** seconds (its 1x1 gif, but server returns if after 30s), via image preloading.

```
window.onload = function () {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () { alert('Yey!'); };
    img.onerror = function () { alert('Doh!'); };
    img.src = 'http://cross-domain.com/1x1px.gif';
};
```

All browsers except Opera's do not show "Loading..." mode. Preloading image via Link, Script, Iframe, CSS - same effect.

How to disable "Loading..." mode while preoading images in Opera?

Comment: "There is crossdomain image, which is loaded for 30 seconds." Do you mean that the download of the image is delayed for 30 seconds? Is it always the case? Is it always 30s?

Comment: Yes delayed for 30s. Im using long polling crossdimain image request for user's internet connections detection